# How to implement autocomplete Elasticsearch in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to elastic search and stuck up with an issue. When a word is searched, I get the result only if I completely type the word.But I would like to get the suggestion when 1st two letter of the word is typed. For example if word 'Apple' is typed I get the result but I want the result when 'Ap' is typed. Could someone help me in this? I am using laravel 5.2

Comment: If that is the one and only case makes you use elasticsearch, try using 'like' in your db queries. That will be much easier. If it is not, please provide your progress. It seems like you want the code, not help.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN my table consist of 2 thousands entries at the moment.So processing normal query search would take time and that is why I am using elastic search.